# How do I bypass entering exit manually at the initramfs prompt?

Tags: boot, initramfs, lubuntu

I installed lubuntu onto my desktop PC and it does not have any other OS on it. Everytime the system boots up, I get to the initramfs prompt. It does not show any errors. If I enter exit, the system proceeds to boot into Lubuntu.

Comment: Some leads here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/76488/system-wont-boot-unless-i-type-exit-at-initramfs-prompt, as well as here: http://dev.overthere.org/wiki/How_to_recover_from_an_initramfs_shell. This too if you're using an older Ubuntu that uses GRUB: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877789&page=2.